# Eclipse SVN freezes on commit

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

When I try and commit using SVN, 1 in 5 times it will just freeze.

[image]

I get this popup. And it stays there forever. Nothing else is in progress.

Clicking cancel still leaves it in Limbo. Unable to cancel.

The only way to cure it is to end task eclipse and start again. Its very annoying.

Does anyone know how to fix it.

Comment: @duffymo Im not sure thats the best solution. Changing my programming environment to fix one issue.

Comment: @JohnHawksley Good idea. I'll check it out next time it does it :) The thing is end task eclipse and then re-doing it, it works first time.

Comment: Are you the only one committing to the repository? What versions are involved (client and server)? What does the Ecplise plugin state as its compliance version?

Comment: @Doomsknight :) I'm using the Subclipse svn provider with Juno (4.2) and I haven't seen this issue.  If you're on Windows it might also be a Windows Firewall issue (not allowing the socket connection).

Comment: @JohnHawksley , Honkytonk. Im updating to Juno. I am on 3.7.2 And was thinking to update just for the sake of it anyway. The SVN I am using is all up-to-date. And yes Im on Windows, connecting to a Domain Windows server. (Visual SVN). Im not the only one using the svn, but I can assure you it happens when my college doesnt commit for days around the freeze.

Comment: Now on 4.2 with Subverse plugin. Time will tell. But I've spammed the commit loading screen. And its getting to it fine with no issues. Yet to commit something useful a few times and see if it stops. I'll keep you updated :)

Comment: @Doomsknight Okay, but be aware there are reported performance issues with Juno, although I have found it acceptable. [Bug repot](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272)

Comment: @JohnHawksley. Updating has done the trick. No crashes since :) If you want to add an answer. I can accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of steps to troubleshoot a frozen SVN transaction:

1. If you're using HTTP/HTTPS as your SVN transport, when this occurs, you could try visiting the raw URL in a browser. That'll confirm the network and the server are not the problem.
2. Updating your IDE and SVN provider always helps, and you get fixes and new features.  I'm a sucker for keeping everything bang up to date.  In your case, updating from 3.7.2 to Eclipse Juno might help.

Also be aware that tomorrow (27th September) is the release day for Juno SR1, which brings its own slew of bug fixes and performance enhancements - don't forget to update :-)

Comment: Thanks man. Is there a way to update Juno without a fresh install? Aka will Help -> Check for Updates, include Juno Updates? :)

Comment: It _should_ do.  It's technically possible to update between releases (Eclipse is built on OSGi modules, which can all be updated).  The crux is, you need the right Update Sites in Eclipse to make it "see" Juno. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953686/can-i-keep-my-settings-upgrading-eclipse-from-indigo-to-juno) might help!